# Keep estimated price visible in checkout using stepper on mobile

Tags: mobile, ux-field, checkout

I want to know if anyone can help me with my problem. I want to switch the stepper in my wireframe. I want to put details in step 2 in step 1 and vice versa. At the same time I want to keep the user aware with the estimated price before s/he process the order. Here's my current wireframe. I want to know what do you think and hope for some good feedback. thank you.

[image]

and here's the switched steps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can split your **Process** button to be able show the estimated price at the end

[image: Spilt Process button to show estimated price]

Answer (score 0):

If you need step two details in step one, then those details are step one details I would assume. I guess it depends on your informational hierarchy but if they need it, it should be there.

This all depends on your specific user goals but I've seen many companies online use a global "cart" price. It just sits somewhere clearly labeled (text or icon) and usually a tool tip reveals cart details. There are a plethora of ways to keep the user updated on their price.

Comment: I want to switch it so the user no need to put effort in inserting his personal detail if somehow he doesn't want to make order because his order doesnt meet the specification on order details.
I understand the global price thing, but I need some suggestion where to put it within the stepper. 

just a note, when user finish with step 1, the system will automatically close the step 1 and open the step 2 instead

Comment: It seems the price is based on selected options by the user? Step one looks good, have all necessary (for updating the price) options appear first to the user, then update the price accordingly.

Comment: yes, it is. with the page automatically change after the user insert his input, don't you think they will accidentally missed the **estimated price**? This thought kinda bother me, but I dont know where else to put the price so the user will be aware of it

Comment: Make it bigger if it's important or animate it in to draw attention.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Following on from Shreyas Tripathy's idea - it would be ideal to keep the estimated price in the same location with the same styling. For Step 1 mockup -
Create a 'Next' button with the estimated price similarly to the 'Process' button with estimated price. The step 1 and step 2 caption bars could display as breadcrumbs at the top.